# How to find boundary of a graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, vertex, boundary

I would like to find the boundary of a graph which each vertex is given its 2D coordinate (x,y). The boundary path must be a closed polygon and cover most area. For example, in the figure, the boundary path would be: 1-2-3-4-1[image]

I can do this by firstly removing all dead ends, and then start from the most left node, then I will keep "turn right" until I end up with the start point. For example, after removing all dead ends (5,8,7) and continue removing dead end (6) I end up with nodes 1,2,3 and 4. After that, I start from the most left node, Node 1. I turn right to node 2. At node 2, I have 2 options: either go to node 3 or node 4. But I keep turning right, so I will go to node 3. At node 3 I only have an option to go to node 4. Similarly at node 4 I only have 1 option to go back to node 1. Since I end up with node 1. I conclude that the path is 1-2-3-4.

However, I am wondering if there is a "magical" function in any existing graph theory libraries that can do it in an elegant way ? Thank you in advance.

Tim

Comment: Is this the equivalent of finding the longest cycle in a graph?

Comment: I'd guess dead end removal is the way to prep the graph before actually identifying the fully enclosed area(s).

Comment: @ihavenoidea not necessarily - consider the case when in edge (2,3) were for more vertex - or even have more complicate structure inside (1,2,3,4) square. I would have add step to remove all vertex with only 2 edge - which may be good idea because it will allow removing the dead-end in `O(V)`

Comment: I've done the code in VB.NET, but it'd be nice if I can use existing functions in Graph Theory. I've looked for a while but I haven't found one yet.